# Explain algorithm for the sum of digits of an integer

Tags: python

So this code gives the sum of digits in an integer, it works just fine but I would like to understand how it works, can anyone break it down for me?

```
def sumOfDigits():
    number=requestInteger(" Please enter an Integer: ")
    answer = 0
    while number > 0:
        remainder = number % 10
        answer += remainder
        number = (number-remainder)/10
    return showInformation("The sum of digits is "+str(answer)+" ")
```

Comment: that's standard modulo (to get the digit) and division (to shift the next digit into unit for the next modulo)

Comment: You should work through the algorithm yourself on paper so you can see for yourself how it works. BTW, `number = (number-remainder)/10` won't work correctly on Python 3, it should be  `number = (number-remainder)//10`, and that can be simplified to `number = number // 10` or `number //= 10`

Comment: I ended up doing it a simpler way, converting the integer to an array and then using sum(array) to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets do a dry run :
number is your input 
suppose number=13
the modulus by 10 leads to 3 as a remainder
we store 3 as a sum in answer
13-3(remainder) leads to 10
now the number is 10/10 which is one (1)
1 modulus by 10 leads to 1 
so answer now is 1+3=4
now number which was 1 - 1 which was remainder leads to 0 which is not according to the loop's condition

That was the dry run:
Taking modulus by 10 gives us the unit's digit .
Subtracting the unit's digit by the number again gives us the number excluding the unit's digit. Again the modulus with 10 is taken for the reduced number.
And all the unit's digits are added to get the sum

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Going to work it on paper and try to understand the underlining concept of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some print information for debug :

```
def sumOfDigits():
number = int(input("Please enter an Integer: "))
print("input bumber is: ", number)
answer = 0
iLoop = 0
while number > 0:
    iLoop += 1
    print("\r\nLoop: ",  iLoop)
    remainder = number % 10
    print("remainder: ", remainder)
    answer += remainder
    print("answer: ", answer)
    number = (number-remainder)/10
    print("number: ", number)
print("\r\nThe sum of digits is "+str(answer)+" ")

sumOfDigits()
```

The output is:

```
Please enter an Integer: 142
input bumber is:  142

Loop:  1
remainder:  2
answer:  2
number:  14.0

Loop:  2
remainder:  4.0
answer:  6.0
number:  1.0

Loop:  3
remainder:  1.0
answer:  7.0
number:  0.0

The sum of digits is 7.0
```